# Page id based on file path?

Tags: 7, uri

My page structure looks a little something like this:

- www.site.com/sub-directory-1/page-1
- www.site.com/sub-directory-1/page-2
- www.site.com/sub-directory-1/page-3
- www.site.com/sub-directory-2/page-1
- www.site.com/sub-directory-2/sub-sub-directory-1/page-1
- www.site.com/sub-directory-2/page-2
- www.site.com/sub-directory-2/page-3

What is the easiest way to make the page's ID the name of the first subdirectory it's stored in?

For example, in the first case, the `<body>` tag should be like the following.

```
<body id="sub-directory-1">
```

Comment: strange question: normaly people want the path for the files depending on the node (not vice versa). or you are migrating your stuff then use a module like migrate. for the first case see:
http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths (or i did not understand your question at all)

Comment: It appears that you didn't understand the question Thomas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your page.tpl.php file, and add this where you have the `<body>` tag.

```
<body class="<?php
   print arg(0, request_path());
?>
```

This will print the first part of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` delimited by a slash. 
`arg()` and `request_path()` are Drupal functions.

Comment: First I would do this in template_preprocess_page and add the class to classes_array. Then I would additionaly wrap it in drupal_clean_css_identifier() for cleaner output of the class in case there are some characters in the path.